# Disable swipe to delete TableView row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView and I'm implementing swipe to delete functionality using the following function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        cities.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        citiesTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

I have a slider on my cells that the user can interact with, however it's fairly easy to accidentally activate the delete swipe action when trying to manipulate the slider.

I would like for there to be an edit button that would enable the swipe to delete action but I haven't been able to make that work.

I've tried to disable cell selection and even disabling user interaction, for both the tableview as well as the cell (which does disable the ability to control the slider but still allows swipe to delete.)

I've also tried to guard the swipe function with a check that an editing button has been pressed.

What is the proper way to do this?

~
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to only support deletion when the table view is in edit mode. However, this means your table will not support swipe-to-delete at all. Instead, when the table view is put in edit mode, the user will see the red circle delete button.

To make this happen you need the following in your table view controller:

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
    // Adjust the following as needed for your table's specific logic
    return self.isEditing ? .delete : .none
}
```

Keep your existing `tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)` method.

To add the Edit button, put the following in `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
```

If you are using a UIViewController with your own UITableView instead of a UITableViewController then you need to override `setEditing` as follows:

```swift
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    self.tableView.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)
}
```

where `tableView` is your own property reference to your UITableView.

With just those 2 or 3 changes, your table view will not support swipe-to-delete which allows your sliders to work without interference. The user can tap the Edit button to enable the ability to delete any row by tapping the displayed red circle delete button. Then they can tap the Done button to go back to non-edit mode.